# Android Studio is not fitting the screen

Tags: android-studio

I updated all the drivers of my PC. Tried all the resolutions, but still the problem exists. I am not able to access the buttons bellow. Please help.

Here is the screen shot, trying to create new project.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug that has plagued Android Studio users for months now running on lower resolutions, such as `1366 x 768`. The window in question cannot be resized.

To progress to the next screen, simply press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

**Edit**:

I can say from experience this bug exists in version 1.3, however I can't confirm if it exists in 1.4.